# ssis-determine updated rows without primary key

Tags: ssis

I have two datasets that are generated on a nightly basis by a vendor.  Neither table contains a primary key, but the rows are unique.  Given an absence of a primary key, is there a way using SSIS to determine which rows have been added, updated, or deleted?  All of the information I have found seems to point to needing a primary key.  Simply numbering the rows would not work because the tables are rebuilt on a nightly basis.

The tables being compared may look something like this:

```
TABLE 1                         TABLE2
Name   Facility   Access         Name   Facility   Access
----   --------   ------         ----   --------   ------
Bob    NJ         Full SA        Bob    NJ         Full SA
Bob    NJ         Full AB        Bob    NJ         Full DS
Bob    GA         Full SA        Bob    GA         Full SA
Bob    GA         Full AB        Bob    FL         Full SA
Bob    CA         Full AA        Janet  CA         Full AA
```

Has anyone faced a similar situation?  I cannot seem to find a way to determine if a row has been inserted or updated (or deleted or updated) in the absence of a primary key. Any thoughts?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Been there yes. Since there's no business key, you won't be able to tell if this new row was an update to an existing row or really a new-new row. You can compute a hashsum across all the keys and at least determine do I have one of these already and then delete what no longer exists and add what's "new" but I don't have a graceful pattern on that. Unless you call lots of caffeine and vulgarity a pattern.

Comment: @billinkc Could you create views nightly and then join on the views to see if there have been updates?

Comment: Since the rows are unique, conceptually, the row is the primary key therefore, regardless physical db events, there will only be inserts and deletes, which you can find by comparing whole rows using a merge join(full join).

Comment: @Jayvee That is the road I am starting to head down.  Since given the situation an update is conceptually both a delete and an insert.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I was trying to stay within SSIS, I would use the Slowly Changing Dimension component for this requirement. After picking TABLE2 as the target table, I would specify that all columns form the Business Key.

This will produce outputs for New and Updated rows, including OLE DB Destination and OLE DB Command components.

I would add another column to TABLE2 to identify "deleted" rows, e.g. LastUpdateDateTime. I would add a downstream Execute SQL task to delete or update those rows.

All that said, I would probably lean towards a SQL MERGE solution as it is more flexible and complete.